# Understanding GUI in Android

Tags: android

I want to know that how to develop application that can run in all android devices .
I have tried to do it but I am facing problem for various devices i.e. i found different GUI in various devices ..
How can i do same GUI for all verion of android and for all screen resolution and density ???
Is there any help ??